# Rails and rspec. uninitialized constant Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a rails App. I have this file app/errors/status.rb

I try to pass the test but is not not working.

```
module Errors 
  class Status
    def initialize status
      @status = status
    end

    def default_message
      "Error in the server status: #{status}"
    end

    private

    attr_reader :status
  end
end
```

And the test on spec/errors/status_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Errors::Status do
  let(:status) { double 'status' }

  subject { described_class.new status }

  describe 'default_message' do
    it 'returns the default message' do
      expect(subject.call).to eq( "Error in the server status: #{status}")
    end
  end
end
```

And it keeps throwing this error:

```
/Users/gerardmorera/bet_play/spec/errors/status_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Errors (NameError)
    from /Users/gerardmorera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
    from /Users/gerardmorera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/gerardmorera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
    from /Users/gerardmorera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/gerardmorera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /Users/gerardmorera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
```

Comment: Your Rails version is ?

Answer (score 1):

That’s because of how ActiveSupport’s auto-loading works and the way in which Rails sets up the `$LOAD_PATH`. Autoload sees `Errors::Status` and expects to find it at `errors/status` somewhere via `require`, but it doesn’t because `app/errors` is in the `$LOAD_PATH`, so you would require your file with just `require 'errors'`.

You can fix this by moving `app/errors/status.rb` to a location ActiveSupport’s auto-loading expects (e.g. `app/<something>/errors/status.rb`). You can `puts $LOAD_ATH` to see all the possible locations (note that Rails will add all directories in `app/` to the `$LOAD_PATH`).

Comment: This answer is good, and more [detail discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382) .

Comment: here is a sweet [reasoning](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382#issuecomment-37702855)

Comment: @Andrew is there any way to fix it without modifying the tree structure? I am not sure if I still understand the problem.
I have other folders at the same level, like services, components, null_object and they do not give any problem...

Comment: Nope. Not without making `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` very angry. Think about it: `app/models/foo.rb` does not contain `Models::Foo`, and likewise it expects `app/errors/status.rb` to contain `Status`, not `Errors::Status`.

Comment: To expand Andrew's comment, considering that `app/models/foo.rb` contains `FooModel`, and and `app/controllers/foo.rb` contains `FooController`, you can rename the error class from `Errors::Status` to `StatusError`. This maintains consistency with both the Rails class naming scheme and Ruby's error naming scheme.